# Swift: How to use HTTPS proxy

Tags: swift, xcode, proxy, urlsession

I have a paid proxy (HTTP/HTTPS/SOCKS).
I can make requests with HTTP scheme, but can't with HTTPS.

I always get en error:

```
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=311 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <69F444DF-8C0E-4F4B-B723-C7BCD72B6C02>.<1>, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <69F444DF-8C0E-4F4B-B723-C7BCD72B6C02>.<1>"
), _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2097}
```

I need to get and parse a few web pages from one concrete domain. I'm trying to use HTTP scheme, but it also fails (i guess due to redirect to HTTPS)

So, my goal is make HTTPS request via proxy server.

My code below:

**Session configuration:**

```
private func getProxySessionConfigration() -> URLSessionConfiguration {
        
        let login = ConfigurationData.proxy.login
        let password = ConfigurationData.proxy.password
        let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        
        let userPasswordString = "\(login):\(password)"
        let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
        sessionConfiguration.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
        
        
        sessionConfiguration.connectionProxyDictionary = [
            "HTTPEnable": true,
            "HTTPPort": ConfigurationData.proxy.port,
            "HTTPProxy": ConfigurationData.proxy.host,
            "HTTPSEnable": true,
            "HTTPSPort": ConfigurationData.proxy.port,
            "HTTPSProxy": ConfigurationData.proxy.host
        ]
        
        return sessionConfiguration
    }
```

**Request function:**

```
public func getPage(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (String?, RequestError?) -> Void) {
        
        let session = URLSession(configuration: getProxySessionConfigration())
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
                if let error = error {
                    completion(nil, .requestFailed(error))
                } else {
                    completion(nil, .unknown(response))
                }
                return
            }
            
            
            if let data = data {
                print(httpResponse)
                if let urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.self.rawValue) {
                    completion(urlContent as String, nil)
                } else {
                    completion(nil, .dataDecodeFailed(data))
                }
            } else {
                completion(nil, .noData)
            }
            
        }
        
        task.resume()
   
    }
```

**Function call:**

```
let requestAvito = AvitoProjectPlaygroud_Sources.RequestAvito()

 let url = URL(string: "https://www.avito.ru/krasnodar/vakansii/voditel_v_yandeks_taksi_zarabotok_ot_1388074044")!


requestAvito.getPage(url) { (htmlString, error) in
    if let error = error {
        switch error {
            case .noData: print("ERROR: no data")
            case .unknown(let response):
                print("ERROR: unknown error")
                if let response =  response { print(response) }
            case .urlFailed: print("ERROR: url generating failed")
            case .requestFailed(let returnedError): print("ERROR: \(returnedError)")
            case .dataDecodeFailed(let data):
                print("ERROR: data decoding failed")
                print(data!)
        }
        return
    }
    
    if let htmlString = htmlString {
        // print(htmlString)
        print(String(htmlEncodedString: htmlString))
    } else {
        print("NO DATA")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your issue first of all (Before ANYTHING else, make sure your proxy handle HTTPS proxying), if no then does not matter the code you put in.

To handle HTTPS Proxying there is 2 keys to use that it seems you are using it. One thing I can see is that you are using true as boolean, etc.

As per my experience I always used value such numeric or string lateral.

Make sure that data is passed as String / Int (true -> 1) etc. That could help.

Sometimes it can make some issues with those assumptions that true "will" be converted as 1.

Here below an example on how I use it:

```
  let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.requestCachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    config.connectionProxyDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any]()
    config.connectionProxyDictionary?[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPEnable as String] = 1
    config.connectionProxyDictionary?[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPProxy as String] = "xxx.yyy.zzz.bbb"
    config.connectionProxyDictionary?[kCFNetworkProxiesHTTPPort as String] = 8888
    config.connectionProxyDictionary?[kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyHost as String] = "xxx.yyy.zzz.bbb"
    config.connectionProxyDictionary?[kCFStreamPropertyHTTPSProxyPort as String] = 8888
```

So in short :

- Verify first your proxy (making sure https proxying is handled)
- and then pass data as above

it may solve your issue hopefully.

Comment: thanks for answer. I've checked your code and got the same issue - error((

Comment: a also checked proxy (using command line) and it works both types - HTTPS and HTTPS